# Designing inheritance functions in sibling classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class `brotherClass` and a class `sisterClass` that both inherit from `parentClass`. A method called `getName()` is defined in `parentClass`. Currently, both child classes call `getName()` in the logic of some of their functions.

Right now, our client wants us to make it such that there is a single class(?) external to both `brotherClass` and `sisterClass` that calls `getName()`. That way, both child classes can call that external function once, instead of twice in their own classes.

I think in a way he wanted to save space/memory. Otherwise, he mentioned that I should implement some function that calls `getName()` somehow in `brotherClass()`, and that `sisterClass` should be able to access that too.

I'm at quite a loss about how to move forward with this, and I pretty much typed this up verbatim. This is a very simplified version of the problem I'm facing at work now.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you want to achieve? Do you want to have the `getName()` result prepared and after that used in both brother and sister class? Or what is the point?

Comment: It sounds like your "client" is suggesting that you favor Composition over Inheritance, but since you didn't understand what they were talking about, you're having a hard time phrasing this into an answerable question. Go ask the client what they meant. Once you understand what they want, then you will know what questions to ask.

Comment: @svz yes i would like to have the getName() result prepared in a class/function external to both brother and sister class BUT they are able to access that result.

Comment: @bouncingHippo Can you elaborate your sentence "instead of twice in their own classes."? How does a child class call a super class method twice?

Comment: @Desolator in this sense that 1 child class contains 1 method to call `getName()` once. so since there are 2 child classes doing the same...wouldnt that be 2x ?

Comment: Go back to the client to get clarification  The question as asked makes no sense to me.  As described, there **is** only one getName() method, in the parent.  Even if there weren't, the memory savings would be miniscule.  And what do you mean by "prepared"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ALL your subclasses have same code, you can put that common code in a super class method:

**Before**

```
public class HelloWorld {
}

public class Child1 extends HelloWorld {
     public void someLogic() {
          [commonCode]
          ...
     }
}

public class Child2 extends HelloWorld {    
     public void someOtherMethod() {
          [commonCode]
          ...
     }
}
```

**After**:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public void common() {
          [commonCode]
     }
}

public class Child1 extends HelloWorld {
     public void someLogic() {
          super.common();
          ...
     }
}

public class Child2 extends HelloWorld {    
     public void someOtherMethod() {
          super.common();
          ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the things you can do depend on the logic you want to implement. You can add a field with `getName()` result to your parent class and when you run brother or sister methods just check if that field contains anything. If it does you use the values from there, if not - you run the full `getName()` logic.

If it doesn't suit, the other way is to create another class like this:

```
class Container{
    Brother b;
    Sister s;
    void doCalculations(){
        Object result = Parent.getName();
        b.runMethod(result);
        s.runMenthod(result);
}
```

There may be other options as well.